# My string value is becoming null when I pass to another activity using intent

Tags: android

```
public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE;
    String[] quantityOfItem = new String[10];
    EditText editText1;
    CheckBox checkBox1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.shopping_page);

         checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
         editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
         Button checkoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
         checkoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

            checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new      CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,   boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {

                        quantityOfItem[0] = editText1.getText().toString();
                    }
                }
            });
            nextActivity(v, quantityOfItem);
        }
    });
}

public void nextActivity(View v, String[] quantityOfItem) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ShoppingPageActivity.this,     BalancePageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, quantityOfItem);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

And I receive it in another activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.balance_page);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String[] quantityOfItemString = intent.getStringArrayExtra    (ShoppingPageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    if(quantityOfItemString[0]==null)
        updateTextView2("AAAAA");
}

public void updateTextView2(String toThis) {
    TextView quantityOfItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    quantityOfItem.setText(toThis);
}

Here is my checkbox and editext xml
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="P001" />
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="45sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2" />
```

however there is always an "AAAAA" displayed althought i thought the first cell of string array contains the value got from editText1

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You haven't assigned any value to the key EXTRA_MESSAGE. Try modifying it as
public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE="message";

Comment: Tried. But still not working

Comment: Add logs in your first activity and check what is the value of `quantityOfItem` in `nextActivity` method

Comment: can you explain what functionality you want to implement?

Comment: If the checkbox is checked then the value in editText will be extracted to output it out

Comment: @Lance - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 0):

Your tag is empty so set it in ShoppingPageActivity

```
 public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE="EXTRA_MESSAGE";
```

then its receive

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String[] quantityOfItemString = intent.getStringArrayExtra    (ShoppingPageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, quantityOfItem); here send value?? check once

Comment: Ya I'm using the putExtra(String name, String [] value) method

Comment: inside nextActivity method check quantityOfItem is null or not?

Comment: Im not sure how can i check that

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't used intent, but I've had similar problems of passed values turning into nulls due to scope - have you tried making the string variable public?

Comment: Have you considered passing the value by reference?

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this if it may help

```
                checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new      CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,   boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {

                            quantityOfItem[0] = editText1.getText().toString();
Log.v("@@@value: "," "+editText1.getText().toString())
nextActivity(v, quantityOfItem[0]);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Actually you were passing the empty value in nextActivity() method

Comment: Still not working. BTw, I'm passing as string array but not string

Comment: I've edited the code, please try this and also check if your locat printing the correct value

Comment: Sorry im new to android. I'm not sure where can i check the value

Comment: Is it this one?

Comment: 07-10 05:23:22.214 1168-1168/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.

Comment: In  your android studio look at bottom panel there will be Android Monitor there you will find our value @@@value

Comment: I try to find in verbose but nothing matches

Comment: And the checkout button is not functioning when i put the next activity method inside is checked

Comment: well that has nothing to do with your button click event  you can put your method there

Comment: try to put only checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener event just comment  checkoutButton.setOnClickListener that is creating problem

Comment: <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="P001" />

Comment: i just edited once more ,try that ,I have removed onclick event and only used setOnChecked event try that

Comment: I think the problem is about the if(isChecked) line. So I posted my checkbox xml code. Can you help me see if there is anything wrong with this code?

Comment: no it looks fine, have you tested by removing the onClick listener of your checkoutButton button?try that and tell me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want start another activity as soon as checkoutButton state is changed, try moving  'nextActivity(v, quantityOfItem);' inside change listener as follows :

```
checkoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

        checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new      CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,   boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

                    quantityOfItem[0] = editText1.getText().toString();
                    nextActivity(v, quantityOfItem);
                }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: The Checkout Button become not functioning instead

Answer (score 0):

Bundle b=new Bundle(); 
 b.putStringArray("key",quantityOfItem); 
 Intent i=new Intent(ShoppingPageActivity.this,BalancePageActivity.class); 
 i.putExtras(b); 
 startActivity(i); 
  
In order to read:  
 
 Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras(); 
 String[] array=b.getStringArray("key");

Comment: [Please format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me for guessing your layout files so I have used relativelayout to demonstrate the solution.

You can setOnClickListener on button on ShoppingPage as you dont want to go to next activity unless user presses button and has checkbox is checked. If you want to go to next activity on checking the checkbox then why would you need button? Hence I am transitioning to next activity only when button is pressed and user has checkbox checked.

If you want to transition to next activity irrespective of the checkbox checked then use the below snippet in onclick of button.

```
checkoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // if checkbox is checked then save data in quantityOfItem
        // next activity i.e. BalancePageActivity
        if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
            quantityOfItem[0] = editText1.getText().toString();
        }
        // go to nextActivity when button is pressed 
        // irrespective of whether checkbox is checked
        // if checkBox is not checked then AAAAA will be displayed
        nextActivity(v, quantityOfItem);
    }
```

ShoppingPageActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ShoppingPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE;
    String[] quantityOfItem = new String[10];
    EditText editText1;
    CheckBox checkBox1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_page);

        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button checkoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        checkoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // if checkbox is checked then only on button press go to
                // next activity i.e. BalancePageActivity
                if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                    quantityOfItem[0] = editText1.getText().toString();
                    nextActivity(v, quantityOfItem);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void nextActivity(View v, String[] quantityOfItem) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ShoppingPageActivity.this, BalancePageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, quantityOfItem);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

BalancePageActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BalancePageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_balance_page);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String[] quantityOfItemString = intent.getStringArrayExtra(ShoppingPageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        if (quantityOfItemString == null || quantityOfItemString[0] == null) {
            updateTextView2("AAAAA");
        } else {
            updateTextView2(quantityOfItemString[0]);
        }

    }

    public void updateTextView2(String toThis) {
        TextView quantityOfItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        quantityOfItem.setText(toThis);
    }
}
```

activity_shopping_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.testing.test.ShoppingPageActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="P001" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_width="45sp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click here"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_balance_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.testing.test.BalancePageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Shopping Page

[image]

Balance Page

[image]